# magento color swatches show text

Tags: javascript

i want that color swatches to show text instead of images,

basically it is some js issue below code is used to show images:

```
elm = new Element('img', {
                                src: '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA); ?>hk_option_swatches/'+item.img, 
                                alt: opt.innerHTML, 
                                title: opt.innerHTML, 
                                'class': 'swatch-img'});
```

now i want this to be span or duv with text inside

i wrote below code to add span

```
elm = new Element('span', {
                                'class': 'mycustomswatcher swatch-img'});
```

The above code adds

how can i add text inside span i wrote below code

```
                    elm.update("g");
```

but it's showing error.

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 1):

To add the innerHtml to your element I think the following will work.

```
elm.innerHTML = 'Your Text Goes Here';
```